# ruby-on-rails tutorials: Can't show a user's microposts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As I was reading "Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial", I was trying to figure out what I did wrong in chapter 11 as I couldn't have the test in listing 11.15 to pass.

So here I am, stuck in section 11.2.1. Since I couldn't get anywhere with it, I decided to ignore this and proceed further: to fill up 50 microposts for the first six users and then try to access a user's show page.  I got the following error page:

```
NoMethodError in Users#show

Showing <my_path>/sample_app/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #10 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #10):

7:       </h1>
8:       <% unless @user.microposts.empty? %>
9:         <table class="microposts" summary="User microposts">
10:           <%= render @microposts %>
11:         </table>
12:         <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
13:       <% end %>
```

With trial and errors, it looks like the instance variable @microposts is nil for some reason.  It looked as if the method "UsersController.show" didn't do its job of creating that instance variable. However, I could verify that this method is executed since I could manage to acces a user's show page successfully provided that he doesn't have any micropost.

At this step, it's hard to give more hints. But I can tell that all the other tests are passing.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing all your occurrences of @microposts with @user.microposts.

Is @microposts defined in your controller action? Or is @user defined in your controller action? Because it seems like @user.microposts is probably the same thing as @microposts (from this context) and unless you've declared a variable for an associated user.microposts object, you might be trying to access a nonexistent variable.

Answer (score 0):

could it be `@user.microposts`?  The thing that on line 8 it checks for the existence of?

Answer (score 0):

Well, with these types of errors, there's a stupid mistake creeping somewhere.

Following the advice of the ruby.railstutorial.org site.  I did compare my code against the one of the author.  Guess what, in my version of UsersController, there was two definitions of the 'show' method!  And that second instance, at the bottom of the file, didn't have any assignment to the @microposts instance variable.

Would I had to compile the thing, the bug would have been spotted. I guess that there must be a way to scan a rails site against a ruby syntax checker.

Anyway, thanks for the other people suggestions.